# using firebase serve from two computers

Tags: firebase

I use firebase and Nodejs on the server side, I use function in firebase.
I currently use 2 computers, on one computer I do "firebase deploy" and on the other computer it checks if the api code is correct in "postman".

My problem: "deploy" is an expensive operation that costs me money, and takes a long time, is it possible to do a "firebase serve", and use the localhost address on my other computer?

Comment: What you mean it costs money ? and for what reason no deploy and serve only

Comment: @Ashish I do deploy many times, and I exceed my bandwidth, and I pay more, the service is cheaper and faster

Comment: Serve only works for local environment. It can't be used for publically

Comment: @Ashish Can you tell me how much I should pay for each GB I exceed in firebase in bandwidth? Firebase listed $ 5 - but that seems excessive to me

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed. Use `firebase serve -o 0.0.0.0` on the computer you want to serve from, then find the IP of that computer on your network (such as 192.168.1.34), and go to `thatip:5000` in a browser. This opens a port on your network, but all traffic will have to go through the serving computer, so it may be a bit slow.

Comment: thank you for the help, can you explain a little bit more, this is not clear to me.

Comment: Where you'd normally not want to run 'firebase deploy', run the above command instead. Assuming you're using windows, you can run 'ipconfig' on the same computer from a different Command Prompt. The address you need to ping/post on your other machine is the one listed under 'IPv4 Address' followed by the port 5000.

Comment: thank you for the help, i try to run ```firebase serve -o 0.0.0.0```, and after that try to run myip with :5000. but this isnt working for me, i cant understand what am i doing wrong

Comment: @Haham Are there any error messages like 404? What's the output of the firebase serve run?